# Fur-covered room

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

UPD just realized I didn't define the problem right. My problem is that the rendering is too slow. It's rendering on 128 samples and it chokes on the 0-1% of render. My computer is mac running on OS 10.10.5 Yosemite.

Complete beginner here. I am trying to visualize a room inlaid with fur and my mac chokes on any amount of strands beyond 4000, which is quite low for a big space like a room.

Any workarounds for this? Am I approaching this from a wrong angle? Ideas are very welcome.

(pic unrelated, just to demonstrate my level)
[image]

Comment: Child particles?

Comment: It starts running out of memory or any other thing with only 4000 strands ? What does geometry you're adding that particle system of Hair type represent ? How many faces, are there any modifiers on the object ? Also you might try child particles indeed. Keep in mind that 3d viewport may become a bit less responsive once particles are added.

Comment: @pycoder Child particles are on, interpolated.

Comment: @MrZak It was a cube, I inverted it and removed one face, so now it's 5 faces. Child particles are on. 3d view indeed goes blind from time to time.

Comment: How is your computer?

Comment: @pycoder I just realized my question omitted the whole predicament. The rendering is too slow! That is my issue. It's rendering on 128 samples and it chokes on the 0-1% of render. My computer is mac running on OS 10.10.5 Yosemite.

Comment: 0-1% is when it is building the scene. Sorry, I wasn't meaning what brand you had or even OS. How much RAM do you have? Are you rendering on the GPU or the CPU? How powerful are they?

Comment: @pycoder The processor is 2,5 GHz Intel Core i7, memory 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3. I don't know what I'm rendering on nor how powerful they are.